# Configuring a java application to work with HBase (Hue-Cloudera)

Tags: java, configuration, hbase, cloudera, hue

Can anybody provide any advice on how I should go about configuring my Java application to work with HBase? Unfortunately, this fundamental step for configuring a java application to communicate with HBase was omitted from the PluralSight course, "Getting Started with HBase" which I am working through. I am working with an Hue Cloudera VM.

I did look at other stackoverflow answers in relation to connecting a java application to HBase however, I was thrown off by their answers alluding to zookeeper:

```
//config
Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create();
config.clear();
config.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", HBASE_ZOOKEEPER_QUORUM_IP);
config.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", 

HBASE_ZOOKEEPER_PROPERTY_CLIENTPORT);
config.set("hbase.master", HBASE_MASTER);
```

Could somebody even help me decipher this proposed configuration (the stackoverflow code above) of a HBase connection in my java application?

Answer (score 0):

Please try with setting hbase rootdir. I am using this configuration and it works for me.

```
Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create();
config.set("hbase.rootdir", "hdfs://localhost:8021/hbase");
config.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "localhost");
config.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", "2181");      

HTable table = new HTable(config, TableName);
```

Comment: @Anuja jain. Thank you for your response. I will try your solution hopefully tomorrow.